# cannot connect client to wireguard server in LAN

Tags: local-area-network, wireguard, tunnel

## 10k feet view

I want to connect my PC in LAN to a server in the same LAN using wireguard to use his services through a tunnel.

### server conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 59080
PrivateKey = server_priv_key

[Peer]
PublicKey = client_pub_key
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

```bash
wg-quick up wg0
```

### client conf

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
PrivateKey = client_priv_key

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub_key
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32
Endpoint = 192.168.1.109:59080
```

```bash
wg-quick up wg0
```

### testing

#### ping

server side

```bash
sudo tcpdump -i wg0 icmp
```

client side

```bash
ping -I wg0 10.0.0.1 # from client
```

But nothing happen, all packets are lost :/

#### traffic monitor

Meanwhile tshark captured the handshake that is not completed:

```bash
sudo tshark -P -i enp1s0 -f "port 59080"

# Capturing on 'enp1s0'
# 1 0.000000000 192.168.1.132 → 192.168.1.109 WireGuard 190 Handshake Initiation, sender=0x7FB460DB
# 2 5.333455455 192.168.1.132 → 192.168.1.109 WireGuard 190 Handshake Initiation, sender=0xD252A2F8
# 3 10.667509903 192.168.1.132 → 192.168.1.109 WireGuard 190 Handshake Initiation, sender=0x3C5D45E2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved it... My fault, one public key had a wrong letter...

I can confirm that the configuration is correct.